# Flutter app cannot write to the Firestore document created manually or by another user

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

In my flutter Firestore messaging app. Two users are creating a different collections with the same id.
I log in with an X account and message Y account. But when I log in with the Y account and try to see the messages sent by the X account, it creates a new document with the same chatRoomID.

Note:- For a very short span of time I can see the messages if I try after sending so many of them.

Here is what I can think of the problem.

Firstly, The rules of cloud Firestore might not be according to the need.

```
 rules_version = '2'; 
 service cloud.firestore {
 match /databases/{database}/documents {
 match /{document=**} {
  allow read, write: if true;
    }
  }
 }
```

Secondly, I think in my conversation.dart file, my stream builder might have the issue.

```
StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
                stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance
                    .collection("ChatRoom")
                    .doc(widget.chatRoomID)
                    .collection("Messages")
                    .orderBy("Time")
                    .snapshots(),
                builder: (context, snapshot) {
                  print('Snapshot had data - ${snapshot.hasData}');
                  if (!snapshot.hasData) {
                    return CircularProgressIndicator();
                  }
                  return ListView.builder(
                      itemCount: snapshot.data.docs.length,
                      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                        return Text(
                            snapshot.data.docs[index].get("Message"));
                      });
                }),
```

Thirdly, In chatRoomScreen( where all the chats are supposed to be shown), when the user taps on a particular user in listTile.

```
createChatRoomAndStartConversation(snapshot.docs[i].get("Name"));
        Navigator.push(
            context,
            MaterialPageRoute(
                builder: (context) => Conversation(
                      chatRoomID: getChatRoomID(
                          snapshot.docs[i].get("Name"), Constants.userName),
                      uid: snapshot.docs[i].id,
                    )));
      },
```

and the createChatRoomFunction is

```
createChatRoomAndStartConversation(String username) {
   DataBaseServices dbs = new DataBaseServices();
   List<String> users = [username, Constants.userName];
   users.sort();
   print("Your username is ${Constants.userName}");
   String chatRoomID = getChatRoomID(username, Constants.userName);
   Map<String, dynamic> chatRoomMap = {
     "ChatRoomID": chatRoomID,
     "Users": users,
};
dbs.createChatRoom(chatRoomID, chatRoomMap);
print("Chat rooom creation successfull. ChatRoomID - $chatRoomID");
}
```

createChatRoom in databaseaServices class is,

```
  createChatRoom(String chatRoomID, chatRoomMap) async {
       return await FirebaseFirestore.instance
              .collection("ChatRoom")
              .doc(chatRoomID)
              .set(chatRoomMap)
              .catchError((e) {
               print(e);
        });
  }
```

To make it reproducible...

If the user is logged in ChatRoomScreen will be shown to the user.

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Scaffold(
  body: Container(
    padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 24),
    color: Colors.black.withRed(40),
    child: Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        Row(
          children: <Widget>[
            SizedBox(
              height: 220,
            ),
            Text(
              "Messages",
              style: TextStyle(
                color: Colors.white,
                fontSize: 25,
                fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
              ),
            ),
            Spacer(),
            GestureDetector(
              onTap: () {
                showSearch(
                    context: context, delegate: UserSearchDelegate());
              },
              child: Container(
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  color: Color(0xff444446),
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12),
                ),
                child: Icon(
                  Icons.add,
                  color: Colors.white,
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        )
      ],
    ),
  ),
);
```

}
}

It would be a great help if you can figure out the issue for me. Thank you.

Comment: Hey! I got it. Actually, the document id had a dot in it.

Comment: It was actually, username1.username2. I don't know why but it was creating two different documents with the same id. If you know why this would happen. Please share.